# multiple timepicker range in chronological order for taking input from userin webpage jquery or any other

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want a UI for the web application so that the user can select time range in chronological order. like the [image: chronological timepicker view]

my requirement is as follows

1) i need the rows to be added dynamically 
2) Need to have the time range check so that added time slot is not displayed for the next row for selection,   so if first row is 00:00 to 00:10 the user should not be able to select time less than 00:10 in the below row 
3) for the time interval the user will be select for the start time and end time, but for the overall table it should be within 24 hours (one day, ie 00:00 to 23:59)

i googled a lot, but could not find any jquery or any other script for achieving the implementation of UI and the corresponding time range selection. Can someone point out how to achieve this with any jquery or other java script library ????

thanks for the help, as i am new to these it will be a great help if someone can help me

thanks 
Dino

Comment: What's the time interval that you want each range to have?  There's a few different ones in your example

Comment: how to acheive what? This is no where near enough detail to do much with.  All you've given is a table with some inconsistent time patterns and a concept to add rows `dynamically`. We shouldn't have to ask 30 questions to figure out your specifications

Comment: i imagine that the user will type each start/end pair, with the script validating the input, and creating a new line upon a `tab` or `enter` or `rightarrow` or `downarrow` keypress in the End Time field if it's valid